# Azure API Management Rest api to get all the subscription key throwing 400 error code

Tags: azure, odata, azure-api-management

I am trying to get all subscription key names that are associated with any APIM products. Could anyone provide me the correct querystring for the request ?

`curl --location 'https://gb-apim-dev.management.azure-api.net/subscriptions/b01ac92a-4fd4-9dc5-2506afa98816/resourceGroups/JLL-GB-RG-APIM-Dev/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/JLL-GB-APIM-Dev/subscriptions?%24filter=%7C%20name%20%7C%20ThoughtSpot-Trusted-Auth%7C%20eq%20%7C&api-version=2022-08-01' \ --header 'Authorization: SharedAccessSignature uid=integration&ex=2023-09-07T08:23:24.0288132Z&sn=fdfd+ggg=='`

Above is the curl, I am using. I am strugle to pass the correct $filter syntax in query string.

$filter : | name | ThoughtSpot-Trusted-Auth| eq |  --- is this correct ?
$filter : {| name | ThoughtSpot-Trusted-Auth| eq |} --- this one ?

I know the syntax for the filter is wrong but could not get any help from any articles.

Here is the microsoft articles for this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/subscription/list?tabs=HTTP

Comment: are you getting the output without using filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially you can use `GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/subscriptions?api-version=2022-08-01` URL to get all the subscription keys which are there in your APIM instance.

[image]

You can get the **`ownerId, scope, displayName, stateComment`** properties from above response which will be used in the $filter parameter as below-

$filter=contains(properties/scope,'products/starter') or contains(properties/ownerId,'1') and contains(properties/displayName,'test_name')

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Do you know the syntax for equals instead of contains? The problem with Contains is It may not give correct subscription keys based on a product. I need all the subscription keys in a single APIM product. If two product has a nearly similar name, contains may include all subscription keys of both products.

Comment: You can use `properties/scope eq 'products/unlimited'` or `endswith(properties/scope, 'products/unlimited')` to get the subscription keys based on a product